# Difference between can & could

Tags: can-could, could

What is the difference between the following sentences? for me both are same.

you can search it in google &
you could search it in google

Comment: but you could search it in google may means that you did search it in google. right?

Comment: "You searched it in Google" means you performed  this action sometime in the past.You "could" (*possibly*) also say: "**I googled it**" or you "could" (another possibility) say: "I did a search on Google".  If the person did not use Google in the past but perhaps it would have been a good idea, then say: "**You could have** searched in Google."

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/can-or-could

Comment: ok, another doubt, why did you use you could (possibly) also say "I googled it" instead of  you can say "I googled it"

Comment: To notify a user you need to place this symbol @ before their username as in @MaxWilliams. *Could* talks about possibility, it is marginally less certain than *can*,  and it is also considered to be more "polite" than "can". **May** I ask if you have read the older question and its answers? I ask because I see you have asked a new question about "can" vs "could", which explains why I'm here at your older question.

Comment: @mari lou, So Can you go? and Could you go? are same meaning. Right, am asking you this because somebody told me that could you go? is not appropriate as Can you go

Comment: If you give me the context I **could** say whether that person was correct. Compare these two: 1. "**You can park here**" and 2. "**You could park here.**" No 1. says you have permission, it might also mean that you have the ability to do this, but normally we would think the statement refers to permission. No. 2 refers to *possibility* A =There is a possibility that you are able to park here OR it might refer to something that was possible in the past, as in: B = Last month you could park for free, now you have to pay". Context will tells us if it is meaning A or B